# Adding selected CSS/JavaScript to Ruby on Rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I just want to add different CSS/JavaScript on different views. Obviously if I put them in layout, they will be added to each view. Also, I don't want to create separate layouts for different views.

I created a layout `layouts/standard.html.erb` with following content in head:

```
<head>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
</head>
```

This is adding no CSS/JavaScript from app/assets folder to the rendered page.

I also tried `<%= yield :javascript %>` in layout and content_for in the view using javascript_include_tag 'filename' but it is giving asset pipeline error.

Comment: Can you post the code in detail about what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use controller specific javascripts like described in the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets):

> When you generate a scaffold or a controller, Rails also generates a JavaScript file (or CoffeeScript file if the coffee-rails gem is in the Gemfile) and a Cascading Style Sheet file (or SCSS file if sass-rails is in the Gemfile) for that controller. Additionally, when generating a scaffold, Rails generates the file scaffolds.css (or scaffolds.css.scss if sass-rails is in the Gemfile.)
>
> For example, if you generate a ProjectsController, Rails will also add a new file at app/assets/javascripts/projects.js.coffee and another at app/assets/stylesheets/projects.css.scss. By default these files will be ready to use by your application immediately using the require_tree directive. See Manifest Files and Directives for more details on require_tree.

I recommend looking through all of that page as well to understand how asset pipeline works.

Comment: Thanks a lot EugZon, this solved lot of my questions